# How to monitor user-specific events or metric in Lambda function?

Tags: api, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, monitoring

I am currently using **AWS API Gateway + Lambda + DynamoDB** to build an API server. (using Serverless framework of course, since I am using Lambda)

My problem is that I don't know how to perform monitoring on the **Lambda** function and **DynamoDB** for later user analysis. For example, I might want to check how many requests a user made in one month (This will be like, in my DynamoDB, I have 100 users. I want to obtain the number of requests that every user made in this month.) Or I might need to check the distribution of requests of every user. (Like, user1 make 10 A requests, 20 B requests,... and user2 make 15 A requests, 30 B requests... and A, B represents different requests, that is different REST API endpoints)

Apart from that, I also want to monitor the response time and error thrown by Lambda. Does anyone recommend some product or service that can solve my problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Serverless Framework comes with a free Pro account. With that is a feature called `tagEvent` where you can tag the invocation with a key value pair. This allows you to later use the invocation explorer in your Serverless Framework Pro account to get only the items from a specific key value pair.

An example of this is:

```js
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  // ... set up some state/custom logic
  context.serverlessSdk.tagEvent('customer-id', event.body.customerId, {
    demoUser: true,
    freeTrialExpires: '2020-09-01',
  });
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'bob' }),
  };
};
```

An example of the invocation explorer filtered by a tag called `user` with a value of `charlie`:

[image]
For more information feel free to check out the official docs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/dashboard/sdk/nodejs#tagevent